# Does the Null spaces of matrix $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and matrix $BA$ equal to each other if the matrix $B$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title says, both $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, I want to prove the Null spaces $Null (A)$ = $Null(BA)$.

I do not know if the statement is correct,
and I am not sure whether my derivation as follows is correct. Is there a new method to prove or any counterexamples？

Proof: $\forall u \in Null(A)$, then $Au = 0$. Multiply $B$ from left, we obtain $BAu=0$, which means any vector $u \in Null(A)$ is a vector in $Null (BA)$.

Similarly, $\forall v \in Null(BA)$, we have  $BAv = 0$. Multiply $B^{-1}$ from left, we obtain $B^{-1}BAv=0$, ie. $Av=0$, which means any vector $v \in Null(BA)$ is a vector in $Null (A)$.

Therefore, we obtain $Null(A) = Null (BA)$, ie., $Ax=0$ and $BAx=0$ have the same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $B$ is invertible, we have that $0 = BAv = B(Av)$ if and only if $Av = 0$ because $B$ is injective. But this precisely that $\ker A = \ker BA.$